# how does program seek out required dll not installed with the program but exists on the computer?

Tags: c++

I made a install exe that does not have any required dll packed with it.
It is my understanding that dynamic library are requested by program on run from the computer.
So how does the program seek out dll that exists on the computer?

Comment: The program asks its operating system: "pretty please?", and the operating system either grants or denies the wish?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  how does the program know what to ask? do I need to pack the lib along when creating the install exe?

Comment: The Loader (the OS process that loads and fixes up your program) calls [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw) to load any DLLs (modules) your main program references.  This process continues (recursively) to load any other necessary modules until all modules are loaded.  If a module cannot be found (see LoadLibrary above for how modules are found) you get the _"one or more missing ..."_ error message and your progam fails to load.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order